# PineScript strange behaviour creating Table. Table is displayed as dot when using IF barstate.islast to create table.cells

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

Hello I isolated code which cause this strange behavior. It is caused by variable price. Is there way around?

```
//@version=5
strategy("My script",overlay=true)


testTable = table.new(position = position.top_right, columns = 2, rows = 1, border_width = 1,border_color = color.white,frame_width = 1,frame_color = color.white)
if barstate.islast
    table.cell(table_id = testTable, column = 0, row = 0, text = "Text 1",text_size = size.large,text_color = color.white)
    table.cell(table_id = testTable, column = 1, row = 0, text = "Text 2",text_size = size.large,text_color = color.white)





price  = request.security(syminfo.tickerid,"D", high[1], lookahead=barmerge.lookahead_on)
crossover = (close > price)
strategy.entry("enter long", strategy.long, 1, when = crossover)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is caused by `barstate.islast`. You creating table cells inside this local block. When cells are not created, with just table variable initialized with `table.new()` function there will be only a dot drawing (table borders without spacing between).

So `barstate.islast` is true for non ticking symbols, or after current last bar is closed (strategy calculates at close of each bar) for RT bars.

Use any other `barstates`, depending of your situation. E.g. `barstate.islastconfirmedhistory` will draw cells when bar is last historical bars. The `barstate.isrealtime` will redraw cells at realtime.

```
//@version=5
strategy("My script",overlay=true)


testTable = table.new(position = position.top_right, columns = 2, rows = 1, border_width = 1,border_color = color.white,frame_width = 1,frame_color = color.white)
if barstate.islastconfirmedhistory or barstate.isrealtime
    table.cell(table_id = testTable, column = 0, row = 0, text = "Text 1",text_size = size.large,text_color = color.white)
    table.cell(table_id = testTable, column = 1, row = 0, text = "Text 2",text_size = size.large,text_color = color.white)


price  = request.security(syminfo.tickerid,"D", high[1], lookahead=barmerge.lookahead_on)

crossover = (close > price)

strategy.entry("enter long", strategy.long, 1, when = crossover)
```